# JList showing old values when clicked

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, jlist

I've been trying real hard to understand `MVC` using `Swing` so I decided to try and make a very basic project and I think I'm close but now the `JList` isn't reacting like I would assume and I'm not seeing it. Could be tired, could be lacking knowledge. Probably both.

My view class `JList` reflects adding or deleting a Person, but when I click it, it reverts to the old values, that -according to the console window- aren't even there anymore. The view class code is below, the entire project can be found [here](https://github.com/ombeletw/OODP-Java-MVC-Swing-Observer)

What am I doing wrong? Am I even "refreshing" the `JList` in a good way?

Here's my view class:

```
public class PersonView extends JFrame implements Observer, ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textFieldFirstName;
    private JTextField textFieldLastName;
    private JButton btnAddPerson;
    private JButton btnDeletePerson;
    private JList listPersons;
    private Observable model;
    private ActionListener listener;

    public Observable getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(Observable model) {
        this.model = null;
        this.model = model;
    }

    public ActionListener getActionListener() {
        return listener;
    }

    public void setActionListener(ActionListener listener) {

        if (listener != null)
            this.listener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public PersonView(Observable model) {

        if (model != null)
            this.setModel(model);

        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblFirstName = new JLabel("First Name");
        lblFirstName.setBounds(10, 11, 68, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblFirstName);

        JLabel lblLastName = new JLabel("Last Name");
        lblLastName.setBounds(10, 36, 68, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblLastName);

        textFieldFirstName = new JTextField();
        textFieldFirstName.setBounds(80, 8, 142, 20);
        contentPane.add(textFieldFirstName);
        textFieldFirstName.setColumns(10);

        textFieldLastName = new JTextField();
        textFieldLastName.setBounds(80, 33, 142, 20);
        contentPane.add(textFieldLastName);
        textFieldLastName.setColumns(10);

        btnAddPerson = new JButton("Add Person");
        btnAddPerson.setActionCommand("Add");
        btnAddPerson.addActionListener(this);
        btnAddPerson.setBounds(232, 7, 192, 46);
        contentPane.add(btnAddPerson);

        listPersons = new JList(((PersonList)model).toArray());
        listPersons.setBounds(10, 61, 414, 150);
        contentPane.add(listPersons);

        btnDeletePerson = new JButton("Delete Selected Person(s)");
        btnDeletePerson.setActionCommand("Delete");
        btnDeletePerson.addActionListener(this);
        btnDeletePerson.setBounds(10, 222, 414, 29);
        contentPane.add(btnDeletePerson);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable changedModel, Object arg1) {

        if (changedModel != null) {

            PersonList personList = (PersonList)changedModel;

            //for debugging purposes
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append(personList.getPersonList().size() + " ( ");

            for(Person p : personList.getPersonList()) {

                builder.append(p.toString() + " ");

            }

            builder.append(")");

            System.out.println(builder.toString());

            setModel(changedModel);

            listPersons = new JList(((PersonList)model).toArray());
            listPersons.setBounds(10, 61, 414, 150);
            contentPane.add(listPersons);
            listPersons.repaint();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == btnAddPerson) {

            if(textFieldFirstName.getText().length() > 0 && textFieldLastName.getText().length() > 0) {

                Person p = new Person(textFieldFirstName.getText(),
                        textFieldLastName.getText());
                listener.actionPerformed(new PersonActionEvent(e.getSource(), e
                        .getID(), e.getActionCommand(), p));

            }

        }

        if(e.getSource() == btnDeletePerson) {

            ArrayList<Person> selectedPersons = new ArrayList<Person>(listPersons.getSelectedValuesList());

            for(Person p : selectedPersons) {

                listener.actionPerformed(new PersonActionEvent(e.getSource(), e
                        .getID(), e.getActionCommand(), p));

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Any help and or insight greatly appreciated, as usual.

Comment: You never seem to add your Observer to your Observable, so I'm not sure how update gets called...personally, it would be simpler to use JList#setModel rather the creating a new list.

Comment: @MadProgrammer the ´addObserver()´ method is called inside the controller. I don't know what would be simpler yet. I'm all new to Swing.

Comment: Personally, I would make the controller the Observer, so it could react to changes within the model and then notify the view, but that's just me

Comment: @MadProgrammer that's indeed another way to do it, but this will suffice to fulfill the requirements. I'll look into that some time. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're update method is being called correctly, the problem may be a z-order issue because you're using a layout manager.

Basically what could be happening is when you add your new list, it's actually being painted underneath the existing list ( which was added previously)

Instead of using a null layout, you should make use of an appropriate layout manager or managers as required. This old have highlighted the issue of multiple of pone to been added to the screen

Additionally, instead of creating a new `JList` when the model changes, simply change the current lists model, for example

```
listPersons.setModel(((PersonList)model).toArray());
```

This is at the heart of the MVC paradigm within in Swing...the fact that you don't need to create a new view, but can simply change its model ;)

Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and [How to use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more details

Comment: actually, I just needed to use the ´DefaultListModel´ as the Oracle docs say. That seems to solve all issues. No refreshing, repainting, re-assignment needed. Thanks (and +1) for the effort.